# Action item you just clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I have this example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wgz4mmm/)

Currently when I click on the title the content appears for all items that have class "title" in CSS.
I want this to be just the item you clicked.

How can I solve this problem?

Importantly, I want to remain the same class name.

*Code HTML:*

```
   <div class="title">Title 1
    <p style="display:none;">CONTENT 1</p>
</div>

<div class="title">Title 2
    <p  style="display:none;">CONTENT 2</p>
</div>
```

*Code Javascript:*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".title").click(function() {
            $("p").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    })
});
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".titlu").click(function(){
       $(this).find$(".top").slideToggle("slow"); //here I think there is a syntax error
    });

});
```

How to make the connection there to "find"?

http://fetr.zonedesign.ro/programe-optionale/

Here I try to implement this example.
If you click on a headline nothing happens although I done it (I think)

Comment: `$(this).find("p")` Here https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/1h2z376v/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

*Code*

```
$(".title").click(function () {
    $(this).find("p").slideToggle("slow"); //OR, $("p", this).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/1h2z376v/)

---

You can also use [`$.fn.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/), However The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

---

Also, You should only use one document-ready handler.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".title").click(function () {
        $(this).find("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").slideToggle("slow"); // this will select all p tags in your DOM.
```

So, target the current element using `this` and use .find() to find the p element inside current element.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".title").click(function(){
        $(this).find("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});


});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0wgz4mmm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".title").click(function(){
    $(this).find("p").slideToggle("slow");

});

});
});
```